# Why was Albus so insistent on this deception?

Tags: grimoire-of-zero

Albus initially portrays herself as male, though we later learn she is female. She was strangely insistent too, going so far as to emphatically say,

> boku wa otoko da! (I'm a man!)

Her high level of offense at getting mistaken for a girl seems a bit odd. I'm not entirely sure what she even gains from this. Was it to make sure the other two main characters don't learn

> that she's the granddaughter of Sorena?

Is that the only reason? Because I would assume that there were many other female witches in her order, so I doubt suspicion would immediately turn towards that conclusion. However, as far as a guarantee, I suppose pretending to be male could be argued to be an optimal way to divert suspicion. But is this the whole explanation?